# Regarding processing of GNSS data heights

Tags: gps, trimble, xyz

I have a TRIMBLE GPS receiver and in its data, I am able to derive the ECEF xyz coordinates. My objective is to obtain the orthometric heights, which I could do using the equation h = H + N.

My question is: Is this way of computing the orthometric height accurate? Are there corrections that I need to perform? Or any errors that I need to take into account?

For example, Geoid model inaccuracies, xyz positioning errors etc.

Comment: What field collection software are you using on the device? I believe their TerraSync software can apply a geoid model. Also, keep in mind, unless you are using the centimeter edition, your GNSS accuracy wouldn't provide highly accurate elevations regardless.

Comment: No, XYZ gives you 3D Cartesian coordinates which are further removed from obtaining orthometric heights. Keep to latitude, longitude, ellipsoidal height, then use a geoid model (EGM2008 or a local model if available) to get N (geoid separation).